# Found this spider in my bed last night.. can someone help ID?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

As I was going to bed last night, this little guy greeted me when turning the covers. Can someone help ID this for me? I'm located in Kentucky, USA.

[image]

[image]

Demonstrating size, compared to a bottle cap:

[image]

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @canadianer Kentucky, USA. I made the appropriate edit, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like an [Agelenopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agelenopsis) to me. According to [www.spiders.us](http://www.spiders.us/species/agelenopsis-spp/), the size, the description and the location (Kentucky) match your specimen.

Here is another image (also from www.spiders.us), for comparison:

[image]

The mentioned link lists 13 species in the Genus *Agelenopsis*. It shouldn't be difficult narrowing it down to species (if that's the correct Genus, of course).